# Change error message in pre-commit hook

Tags: svn, centos, svn-hooks

I've a hook script in a repository that stops a commit if a repository is on the limit of space, but when it prints the following message:

[image]

I need to change the two final lines, somebody knows where can I change it? I'm on centOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two last lines comes from a PO ([Portable Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_object_%28computing%29)) file, which contains translation for all SVN versions.

You wouldn't be able to change it without having to recompile SVN itself, or at least re-generating the the binary [`.mo` files](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/MO-Files.html#MO-Files) with [msgfm](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgfmt-Invocation.html).